# :before and :after not working with table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am trying to add double border to my table I am getting one by "border property of table" for second I am using `:before` and `:after` but its not working.
I am new to CSS and html and try my level best to find out the solution but failed. Any help will help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#banner table:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    border-top: solid 1px;
    border-color: #888;
    border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
    margin: 10px 0 1.25em 0;
                      }

#banner table:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    border-bottom: solid 1px;
    border-color: #888;
    border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
    margin: 1.25em 0 10px 0;
            }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="banner">
<div id=myTable>                                    <table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="hjsb"><label for="what">What are you looking for</label></td>
<td class="hjsb" colspan="2"><label for="where">Location</label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class=""><span class="inwrap"><input class="input_text" maxlength="512" size="31" name="q" autocomplete="off" id="what"></span><div style="width:250px"><!-- --></div></td>
                                                <td class=""><span class="inwrap"><input class="input_text" maxlength="64" size="27" name="l" autocomplete="off" id="where" value="Location"></td>
                                                <td class="" style="width:1px"><input type="submit" class="input_submit" value="Search Jobs"></td>                                      </tr>                                           <tr>
<td class="" colspan="3"><label for="what">Advanced Job Search</label></td>
</tr>                                       </tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use a "div" including table inside it? Is easier than use a ":before" and ":after" properties. I don't know another solution.

Comment: i tried with div.. its working with it but why its not working with table

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work as supposed, the only problem I see is that the border is almost transparent and it seems to be white as the background, i've put a fiddle for you to test it:

http://jsfiddle.net/f5ow7mxg/

If you remove:

```
border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
```

From:

```
#banner table:before {}
#banner table:after {}
```

The borders show up as expected.

Comment: I change color to border-color: rgba (226, 17, 17, 0.25) but in this case border is coming only for first column.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of styling table:before and table:after, why not use #myTable:before and #myTable:after, like this:

```
#banner #myTable:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    border-bottom: solid 1px black;
    margin: 10px 0 1.25em 0;
}

#banner #myTable:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    border-bottom: solid 1px black;
    margin: 1.25em 0 10px 0;
}
```

Just change thye border color, I just made it black to let you see that it works.

[here's the fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/yvmqvtq4/)